# How to fix auto adding forward slash

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my models.py I have a function property that return thumbnail url

```py
return os.environ['BASE_URL'] + self.thumbnail.url
```

my .env file

```bash
BASE_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

but it keep adding 1 more forward slash ( / ) after my BASE_URL

http://127.0.0.1:8000//media/uploads/...
Anyone know how to fix this

Comment: use os.join(os.environ(..), self.thumb....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use urljoin from urllib

```py
from urllib.parse import urljoin

urljoin(os.getenv('BASE_URL'), self.image.url)
```